# how to install libXScrnSaver on opensuse 42.3 tumbleweed

Tags: opensuse

I'm trying to install libXScrnSaver on opensuse 42.3 tumbleweed.

I couldn't install successfully becuase of below error.

```
rajkumar@linux-7owj:~> sudo rpm -i Downloads/slack-3.0.5-0.1.fc21.x86_64.rpm 
[sudo] password for root: 
warning: Downloads/slack-3.0.5-0.1.fc21.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID bf6a7041: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libXScrnSaver is needed by slack-3.0.5-0.1.fc21.x86_64
        libappindicator is needed by slack-3.0.5-0.1.fc21.x86_64
```

Looks like some the libraries are missing.

I tried to install libXScrnSaver by the below command but that too failed.

```
rajkumar@linux-7owj:~> sudo zypper install libappindicator
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'libappindicator' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'libappindicator' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

How can I successfully install the missing dependencies and the slack as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to install application by ignoring dependences and it works.
But I had installed the libXScrnSaver-devel.

```
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/42.3/oss//openSUSE:Leap:42.3:Update.repo

zypper ref
zypper in libXScrnSaver-devel
zypper in slack-3.0.5-0.1.fc21.x86_64.rpm*

Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides libXScrnSaver needed by slack-3.0.5-0.1.fc21.x86_64
 Solution 1: do not install slack-3.0.5-0.1.fc21.x86_64
 Solution 2: break slack-3.0.5-0.1.fc21.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c): 2
```

Comment: Slack installation is successful even though I get error  libXScrnSaver dependency is not found error even after I installed libXScrnSaver which is weird.